# convex cone in complex Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

A convex cone is defined as (by Wikipedia):
A convex cone is a subset of a vector space over an ordered field that is closed under linear combinations with positive coefficients.

In my research work, I need a convex cone in a complex Banach space, but the set of complex numbers is not an ordered field. Then how to define a convex cone in a complex Banach space? I tried to define such a partial order on $\mathbb C$ so that it can be a total order on $\mathbb C$  but I could not succeed.

Comment: Convex cones are defined the same for complex Banach spaces as they are defined for real Banach spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a complex Banach space and $C \subseteq X$, then $C$ is  called a convex cone if $x,y \in C $ and $s,t \in [0, \infty)$ imply that $sx+ty \in C$.